# Unable to apply KMS Key to AWS CloudWatch Log Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-cloudwatch, roles, amazon-kms

I am trying to add symmetric KMS key while creating Log Group in Amazon CloudWatch. I have logged in as root user. The key is created and does exists. But still getting below error:

[image]

Is there any permission or role needs to be given to resolve this?